# Defective PC replaced everything

Tags: desktop-computer, defective-hardware

two weeks ago my PC began not to give any signal to the monitor, mourse, or keyboard.

There are no beep sounds at all, all fans are turning on, GPU lights up, I'm not sure if its POSTing or not but probably not.

I suspected it would be the motherboard or PSU. I had it in warranty, the technician came and literally replaced the PSU, MOBO, and the GPU. Still same problem.

This is literally a new PC, and it still has the same problem, what would be the cause? The only thing we can do now is replace the CPU, but we both know that it probably will not have any effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Specs:
RTX 3060 Ti
Ryzen 5800
550W PSU
B550 MOBO
16GB RAM

Comment: Can you tell if the PC actually turns on?  Does it appear to POST?  I realize you have no display but you should most PCs provide a beep of some kind when they encounter a problem.  What changes 2 weeks ago other than your display not working?  You should be editing your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Edited, and no, there are no changes at all, very weird. Even the technician was surprised.

Comment: ok weird thing to consider, but is the power good and clean at the outlet that the PC is plugged into? I've seen bad power cause this kind of issue before.

Comment: Tried five different outlets

Comment: I'd consider this the time to tell the manufacturer/seller that you want a complete swap for a new machine under your country's consumer protection equivalent of the "lemon laws".

Comment: Have you checked if the monitor is good?

Comment: The monitor is definitely good, don't have any other machines to test it, mouse is not lighting up on the PC but it lights up in my windows tablet normally.

Comment: If their technician with hands-on couldn't fix it, then I doubt we're going to figure it out from a description in text. Send it back. I'm frankly surprised he didn't certify an RMA right there & then & left you with a non-functioning machine under warranty.

Comment: Yes he is going to try replacing the CPU and memory next time for one final shot, then I'll send it back if all fails